# How to draw a marker or similar indication arrow on screen and keep at the same position until I move it?

Tags: windows-xp, portable

How can I draw a marker or similar indication arrow on screen and keep it at the same position until I move it?

I need freeware, portable for Windows XP.

I want to use this type of tool in presentations.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for [ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx).

When in drawing mode, simply press **e** to erase everything, and <kbd>Esc</kbd> or right-click to exit draw mode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is good but i need something like cool 3d arrows , highlight marker,

Comment: If you're pre-recording a presentation to play in a video, check out Wink http://www.debugmode.com/wink/ or Jing http://www.jingproject.com/ , both can make "cool 3d arrows" and highlight items.

Comment: no i'm not asking in video.